# Is there a way to prevent web dynos from going to sleep?

Tags: java, heroku

I'm developing an application that fetches data from an api every 10 seconds and stores it in my own database. When I run it locally it works fine but when hosted on heroku my dyno goes to sleep and stops my app from performing its sheduled task. So my question is, can I disable the dyno sleep function? or is there an even better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Free dynos on Heroku go to sleep when they are not receiving web requests. You can keep them from going to sleep by [upgrading to a paid dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types#available-dyno-types).

Comment: You can also keep it awake by setting up a service to make a wed request every few seconds/minutes. Pingdom is popular for this.

Comment: I don't that technique works anymore. Heroku caught wind of it and stopped it to force you to upgrade.